# Create multiple saved Macro file in path based on active excel "A" column and in each WB update "HR(sheet name)" Cell D4

Tags: vba, excel

How to create multiple Macro file which is already saved in path.. based on employee names in excel "A" column and in each macro workbook need to update in "HR(sheet name)" Cell D4 need to update employee name same as column "A".... am looking for VBA code it will really much appreciable.... am new to here in vba ...  we are doing manually 10000 names , creating multiple Macro files every month.

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub Rename_Multiple_Files()

'Declare Variable 
Dim path_dir As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim row_cntr As Long
Dim column_old_file As String   
Dim column_new_file As String

'Assign values to string variable for old and new file name
column_old_file = "A:A"
column_new_file = "B:B"

'code to select input file folder and rename filename using Do Until loop
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
path_dir = .SelectedItems(1)
file_name = Dir(path_dir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
Do Until file_name = ""
    row_cntr = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    row_cntr = Application.Match(file_name, Range(column_old_file), 0)
    If row_cntr > 0 Then
        Name path_dir & Application.PathSeparator & file_name As _
        path_dir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(row_cntr, "B:B").Value
    End If
    file_name = Dir
Loop
End If
End With

MsgBox "All files renamed successfully", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: All questions you have asked till date has shown no efforts from your side. Other users have already shared with you that you need to show what you have tried but again here you are... expecting people to give you code in a platter? This is simply ridiculous.

Comment: its too long to add here .... let me tell you what have tried ... i made break up ... created manually multiple macro files in same path and used below code..... and am not able to change cell value in given sheet name

Comment: You will have to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. What you want is very simple. How long that code can be? :)

Comment: Finally updated .... column A is for my names which i was doing manually created and pasted into A column and Column B is my new Data replaced that macro file names .... now i need to add Column B values into my all workbooks in HR sheet D4 cell ... could you please help me

Comment: listing here exactly what am looking. 1) macro file save same as as it is in path based on excel column "A" ( if Column has 500 it has to create 500 macro files and rename it ) 2) For each macro files in that have HR as sheet name there need to save Column name or its file name in D$4 in all the workbooks .... I know its difficult to do

Comment: Sure. Now I would love to help you :) I am not able to understand what you want. So Col A has Names. What does Col B have?

Comment: macro file  i have already saved in path....  without manuall work automatic create multple same macro file based on column A names and same name need to update in HR sheet name cell value D4 in all workbooks

Comment: Past from one month tried all possibilities ... i know its more difficult to do VBA here.... Much appreciable your help ...

Comment: you want to create a copy of a macro file and rename it using values from Col A and Col B? and in the new copy, there is a sheet called "HR". You want to write name of the file in Cell D4? is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes correct .... yes can help me based on column A names - create multiple macro files and file name should be in HR SHEET D4 ....  ignore column B here ....

Comment: Macro file saved in local c drive .... so multiple needs to create automatic based on column A names ... same file name need to update in all the macro workbooks ... sheet name called HR in that D4....

Comment: Much appreciable....  is that so difficult to you????

Comment: `Much appreciable.... is that so difficult to you???? – Basavaraj k.s. 6 hours ago` No it is not but I also have a life outside stackoverflow ;) I am outside and will look at your question tomorrow

Comment: Sure will be waiting for your response...

Comment: What does column A have?  Just File name or Path and File Name?

Comment: Column A only File names it may be 3000 or 4000.... and default you can give any path or same path also fine for me

Comment: Macro file is xlsb format.... already saved file in c drive .... same path you can give or any other also fine

Answer (score 0):

> you want to create a copy of a macro file and rename it using values from Col A and Col B? and in the new copy, there is a sheet called "HR". You want to write name of the file in Cell D4? is my understanding correct? – Siddharth Rout 2 days ago
>
> Yes correct .... yes can help me based on column A names - create multiple macro files and file name should be in HR SHEET D4 .... ignore column B here .... – Basavaraj k.s. 2 days ago

I have commented the code so you should not have any problem understanding it.

Logic:

1. Let user choose the macro file
2. Let user choose the output folder. Ensure that there is nothing in the folder as everything will be deleted in that folder
3. Loop though Col A and create copies of the macro file
4. Use `DIR` to loop through the output folder and insert the filename in cell D4

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim flMacro As Variant, outputfolder As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim StrFile As String

    '~~> Ask user to select the macro file
    flMacro = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm),  *.xlsm", Title:="Please select the macro file")

    If flMacro = False Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Ask user to select the output folder
    '~~> Whatever folder user chooses, ensure that there are no files
    '~~> as every file will be deleted in that folder
    outputfolder = BrowseForFolder()
    If outputfolder = False Then Exit Sub
    If Right(outputfolder, 1) <> "\" Then outputfolder = outputfolder & "\"
    Kill outputfolder & "*.*"

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Copy the macro file
        For i = 1 To lRow
            FileCopy flMacro, outputfolder & .Range("A" & i).Value
            DoEvents
        Next i
    End With

    '~~> Loop through each file in that folder and open it
    '~~> Write the filename and clode the file
    StrFile = Dir(outputfolder & "*.xlsm")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(outputfolder & StrFile)

        wb.Sheets("HR").Range("D4").Value = Left(StrFile, (InStrRev(StrFile, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

        wb.Close (True)
        DoEvents
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

'~~> Function to choose Folder
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder for output. Any exisiting files in the folder will be deleted", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Where ever you see `.xlsm`, change it to `.xlsb`. Also ensure that you have `.xlsb` in Col A of the excel file/

Comment: am very close .... not getting how to fix ... D4 only file name required... Column A only file names and i dont want to add for all files xlsb manually,,,

Comment: Shall I wait for your response ?

Comment: I am trying my best but I am not able to understand what you are saying. :(

Comment: Hope your getting what exactly am looking .... much appreciated if you fix this ..... have tried all possible ways

Comment: HR sheet D4 cell Instead of file A.xlsm .... am looking only "file A" in D4 .... see right side ur screenshot

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of file names in Column A

Comment: Am not able to add screenshot .... are you getting what am looking .... shall I explain again ???

Comment: www.wikisend.com. Add the screenshot there. or any other free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: Ur code perfectly working but I need small change in that ....  In HR sheet ...in  D4 cell file name should copy .....  if I run ur code in D4 IT GIVES ME file name + xlsm..... so need changes there I need only file name in D4 Cell

Comment: What do you have in Col A? "FileA.xlsm" or "FileA"?

Comment: No change .... still same .... please run code once .... column A keep only fileA names .....  you will come to know where exactly issue is

Comment: Column A names run once .... see output folder macro files ....  .... if I add column A ... file name with xlsm.... see output folder and open any macro files HR Sheet see D4 Cell ....  actually Column A have names ... I use only xlsm all column A names .... so D4 cell only column A names required.... like abc ....... ( don't want ABC.xlsm). Hope this comment helps to find difference..... much appreciated for your help

Comment: Change the line to `wb.Sheets("HR").Range("D4").Value = Left(StrFile, (InStrRev(StrFile, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))`

Comment: Awesome perfectly done !!! Thank you so much for your help.... i dont know my question simple or tricky ....  am sorry for again and again asked you questions

Comment: I will come back with new difficult one .... New question with my workings

Comment: Create a new post for a new question.

Comment: Sure Siddharth Rout..... I really thankful to you MASTER and appreciate your work... hope for my team it's help a lot ....